# How to create space between image and centering text in html fragment

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to figure out how to create spacing between an image and text for a header type fragment and am not coming up with anything that works as needed.  (not sure if it being a fragment matters or not - I'm an html novice at best)

What I would like is to have the image display/anchor on the far left side and the header text in the center.  The current code below has the image where I want it to be, but the text follows right after which I see why because there are no attributes stating what to do with that text, hence this reaching out seeing I am not sure what to do for that.

I've tried using hspace and that pulled the image over to the right along with the text. Plus other examples I referenced did not speak to what I am looking to do.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <header th:fragment="header">
        <br/>
        <h1> <img th:src="@{/images/my_logo.png}">My Header Text</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html> ```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
````

Comment: Just as a note, this doesn't look like it's ordinary html/css, but also using (probably) Thymeleaf as server side Javascript template? -- Also, can you give us a small drawing how it should look like? Helps it to understand it better as it's probably just needs a bit CSS and structuring

Comment: Thanks.  trying to get the image loaded up now to the post.

Comment: @Hoargarth - yes it is Thymeleaf and you are right on it needing some CSS.  I went with what Johannes suggested below and all is now good.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a `margin-right` to the image:

```css
h1>img {
  margin-right: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300">My Header Text</h1>
```

Note: I added `vertical-align: middle;` here to vertically center-align the text with the image.